# How to execute nested queries within async and conditional loop in node.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, async.js

I am using node.js,express and postgres db for my project. I have few queries in async function which I am not able to execute in a sequence. sample code for reference.

```
for(let i=0;i<person_size;i++)
{
    var check_person_query="select per_id_pk from person_tbl where per_fname='"+person_fname[i]+"' and per_lname='"+person_lname[i]+"'";

    dbClient.query(check_person_query,function(err,result){
        if(result.rows.length>0)
        {
            console.log("Call: 1.1");
            console.log("person already exists");
        }
        else
        {
            var insert_person_query = "insert into person_tbl (per_fname,per_lname,per_gender,profile_photo) values('"+person_fname[i]+"','"+person_lname[i]+"','"+person_gender[i]+"','profile_photo_link')";
            //console.log("query2: "+insert_person_query);
            dbClient.query(insert_person_query,function(err,result){
                    if (err) throw err;
                    console.log("Call: 1.2");
                    console.log("New person has been added");       
            });

            var fullname = person_fname[i].concat(person_lname[i]);
            low_fullname = fullname.toLowerCase();

            person_pic[i].mv("/home/aniket/content_info/images/"+low_fullname+".jpg", function(err){
                if (err) throw err;
            });                                             
        }
    });
}//end for
```

In above code, when if condition fails, the else part gets executed in the very end of my async.series function.  As long as if condition succeeds, everything works perfectly in sequential manner. How to sequentially run nested db queries? I have used async.waterfall but still no expected output.

UPDATE: (SOLVED)

Instead of using nested query functions, I removed the nesting, and prepared a single query so that I would obtain an expected result and maintain the execution sequence.

Comment: You can always use promises and async/await, the latter naturally works with loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really just use async/await. The [pg lib supports promises](https://node-postgres.com/), so you can just do this:

```
for(let i=0;i<person_size;i++) {
  const result = await dbClient.query(check_person_query);
  if(result.rows.length <= 0) {
    await dbClient.query(insert_person_query);
  }
}
```

Here's some more info on [using for loops with async/await](http://thecodebarbarian.com/common-async-await-design-patterns-in-node.js.html#retrying-failed-requests).

Comment: Thanks @vkarpov15 for the detailed answer. I was banging my head against wall to get the solution. As a workaround, I had to eliminate the need of nested query functions. Still there was a question  why didn't nested queries work at all. I will give your solution a try.

Comment: In terms of the performance, this solution will be the slowest, as it will be fully synchronous. A proper solution should be asynchronous, and with joint queries where possible. And, it would depend on the range of values within `person_size`.

Comment: This solution wouldn't be fully synchronous, that's why it is called async/await :)

Comment: @vkarpov15 That's what it's called? LOL. So you don't know that `async/await` acts as a blocking operation in JavaScript. This code will execute synchronously.

Comment: @vitaly-t So how could we develop a solution in faster way?

Comment: @vitaly-t I am working with 1000+ records, will it be slower for this size or it would be enough?

Comment: Try running this gist and then tell me whether async/await is blocking @vitaly-t . https://gist.github.com/vkarpov15/35f1ba08eec70963865bddaad9336082 If you're going to be blatantly wrong, at least keep your misinformation to yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I have just moved image handling code inside the callback of query function, so it should run sequentially.

```
for(let i=0;i<person_size;i++)
    {
        var check_person_query="select per_id_pk from person_tbl where per_fname='"+person_fname[i]+"' and per_lname='"+person_lname[i]+"'";

        dbClient.query(check_person_query,function(err,result){
        if(result.rows.length>0)
        {
            console.log("Call: 1.1");
            console.log("person already exists");
        }
        else
        {
            var insert_person_query = "insert into person_tbl (per_fname,per_lname,per_gender,profile_photo) values('"+person_fname[i]+"','"+person_lname[i]+"','"+person_gender[i]+"','profile_photo_link')";
            //console.log("query2: "+insert_person_query);
            dbClient.query(insert_person_query,function(err,result){
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("Call: 1.2");
            console.log("New person has been added");

            var fullname = person_fname[i].concat(person_lname[i]);
            low_fullname = fullname.toLowerCase();

            person_pic[i].mv("/home/aniket/content_info/images/"+low_fullname+".jpg", function(err){
                if (err) throw err;
            });
        });

        }
    });
    }//end for
```

Comment: Even I also thought that it could be the main barrier but, being a newbie to asynchronous structure I was wrong.